# how to create electron desktop app with existing angular2 project

Tags: php, mysql, angular, firebase, electron

I have an angular2 project which uses mysql, php, jspdf and firebase.

I tried to find it with lots of github sources but it does not work!

The problem is, i have to run it on desktop without internet.

So how can i convert an existing angular2 project to electron desktop app and package it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

I figured out with this. It is really simple.